# App crashing when I come back in my TableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Are some days that I'm trying to adjust a issue that make my app crash during the dismiss, my code is this

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class CourseClass: UITableViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var map: MKMapView!
     struct User {

        var name: String
        var images: UIImage
        var coordinate: (Double, Double)
        var type: String
        var address: String
    }
    var rows = 0 
   var users = [User]()

    let CS = User(name: "Sporting Club", images: UIImage(named: "Caffè Spagar.png")! , coordinate:(12345,54678), type: "Sport", address: "Via dei Cocchieri, 1A")
    let D = User(name: "94Tele", images: UIImage(named: "Duks.png")! , coordinate:(13345,54128), type: "Restaurant", address: "Via della Madonna dei Monti, 94")
    let PS = User(name: "Chiostro del Bramante ", images: UIImage(named: "Posta station.png")! , coordinate:(18795,34556), type: "Museum", address: "Arco della Pace, 5")
    let B = User(name: "Teatro Sala Umberto", images: UIImage(named: "Barnum.png")! , coordinate:(46655,43554), type: "Theater", address: "Via della Mercede, 50")
    let EC = User(name: "Mangiarte", images: UIImage(named: "Elephant Club.png")! , coordinate:(12325,21435), type: "Restaurant", address: "Via degli Equi, 16")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      map.showsUserLocation = true
      map.delegate = self

      users.append(CS)
      users.append(D)
      users.append(PS)
      users.append(B)
      users.append(EC)
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        insertRowsMode3()
    }

    func insertRowsMode2() {
        for i in 0..<users.count {
            insertRowMode2(ind: i, usr: users[i])
        }
    }

    func insertRowMode2(ind:Int,usr:User) {

        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)

        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)
    }    

   func insertRowsMode3() {
        rows = 0  
        insertRowMode3(ind: 0)
    }

  func insertRowMode3(ind:Int) {
        let indPath = IndexPath(row: ind, section: 0)
        rows = ind + 1
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indPath], with: .right)

        guard ind < users.count-1 else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now()+0.15) {

            self.insertRowMode3(ind: ind+1)
        }
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return rows
    }

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyTableViewCell

      let user = users[indexPath.row]

        cell.myImage.image = user.images
        cell.myLabel.text = user.name
        cell.myTypeLabel.text = user.type

        return (cell)
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLast" , sender: users[indexPath.row])

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 100
    }

    @IBAction func mapTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let latitude:CLLocationDegrees = 41.8919300
        let longitude:CLLocationDegrees = 12.5113300

        let regionDistance:CLLocationDistance = 1000;
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude)
        let regionSpan = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinates, regionDistance, regionDistance)

        let options = [MKLaunchOptionsMapCenterKey: NSValue(mkCoordinate: regionSpan.center), MKLaunchOptionsMapSpanKey: NSValue(mkCoordinateSpan: regionSpan.span)]

        let placemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinates)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: placemark)
        mapItem.name = "My House"
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: options)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToLast" {

        guard let vc = segue.destination as? FinalClass else { return }

        let guest = segue.destination as! FinalClass

             if let user = sender as? User {

            guest.local = user.name

             guest.localImage = user.images

            guest.localType = user.type

            guest.localAddress = user.address
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

so when i go in the other scene it's all okay but when i want to come back

```
@IBAction func lastBack(_ sender: Any) {

    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

my app crash because of this

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (5), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

I really don't know how I can adjust my code to make it work.

Comment: it's really hard to read your code. crash log explains the problem but you can only understand the problem by debugging, don't forget viewdidappear is called every time when app is foreground, so if you go to another controller and back to this controller again, viewdidappear will call again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error itself says the says the problem. There is some inconsistency with `rows` data.

As you can see, when you are first visiting this `CourseClass` controller you are setting up row by calling `insertRowsMode3` in `viewDidAppear`.

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    insertRowsMode3()
}
```

The problem is when you return back the `row` data is not same as you have initialised it with `zero` and `viewDidAppear` doesn't get called. I will suggest avoid putting your `data` in or view controller, it violets the core architecture of `MVC` including data layer at wrong place.